# How do I manipulate the header of a csv file stored in hdfs according to the options available in dataframeWriter?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a functionality which writes a dataset into a location in the hdfs . I noticed that in case the dataset is a result of union or join functionality more than 1 part is created in the hdfs. The contents of the location is as follows :-

1. _SUCCESS
2. part-00000-7908d1be-5409-4ac4-a218-29b9b1f99449
3. part-00001-7908d1be-5409-4ac4-a218-29b9b1f99449

If "dataset" is the dataset to be stored in hdfs at location "locale" with  dataframeWriter csv options (header , sep, qualifier ) are stored in "options" (header being true always), as follows:-

```
  DataFrameWriter dataFrameWriter = dataset.write();
  if(options != null && !options.isEmpty()) {
                dataFrameWriter = dataFrameWriter.options(options);
            }
            dataFrameWriter.mode(saveMode).csv(locale);
```

This is then merged into a single part using fileUtil "copyMerge":-

```
  if(fileUtil.copyMerge(fileSystem,sourcePath,fileSystem,destinationPath,true,hdfs
  Config,null)){
        fileStatus = fileSystem.getFileStatus(destinationPath);
    }
```

CopyMerge() is a  function that take all contents of the location and merges them and writes them in the provided destination path.

The problem I am facing in each chunk the header is written, and by copyMerge the header is repeated more than once:-

```
    Header1,Header2,Header3
    x,y,z
    a,b,c
    Header1,Header2,Header3
    r,t,y
    h,y,d
```

I tried solving it by making the "header" option false and writing the header as a string using outputStream into the same location and then calling the copyMerge, as already mentioned.

```
 String separator = (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(options.get(SEPARATOR)))? 
  options.get(SEPARATOR):",";
    String header = String.join(separator,dataset.columns());
    header = header+'\n';

 InputStream stream = new 
           ByteArrayInputStream(header.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

 writeFile(location + "/header", stream); //this being another function that writes the stream into the location
```

The problem I am facing with this approach is I have to manipulate the header for all csv options like "escapeQuotes", "quoteAll" etc, just like I am manipulating the header for the separator.

Is there any way I can handle this header issue, without having to manipulate the header differently.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want it in a single file? You can always call `coalesce(1)` on your dataset - that will put everything in a single partition and store it in a single file. However, that requires your dataset to be small enough that everything will fit into a single partition.

Comment: The scenario is :- I have to store the result of any operation (in the form of a dataset) into a csv file . This file can later be downloaded or used if required .

Comment: yes, I got that from you question, but I ask again - why is it important that it is put into a single file? Spark writes it a several parts - why not just keep it that way?

Comment: The issue is not merging . The issue is if header is true , each part created ends up having the header , so even if I open an InputStream and read this file , the header is repeated. Is there anyway I can skip writing of header for all other parts except the first part (part_00000 ..).

Comment: Oh, I see - you are reading the file(s) with other non-spark applications. Okay, then AFAIK, you have only the option of specifying no headers at all - or as I wrote in a comment put everything into a single file.